# IOS 7 Issue For My MGWT Application

Tags: ios, gwt, cordova, gwt-rpc, mgwt

I have created one MGWT application with the help of RPC,PHONEGAP&GWT technologies.My application is working properly until IOS 6 version ,In IOS 7 my home screen is shrinking when  i am tapping one icon,in that opening one drop down list and directly get back into my home screen, at that time my home screen is not displayed properly. Please look into my issue .
Thanks in advance..

For Example: The Complete structure of my application. First Login screen .After login into my application home screen is coming ,in that settings,about..etc icons are there.In that i am selecting settings icon in that work type drop down list is there and i am tapping work type then tap the back button coming to home screen at that time my home screen is not displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS 7, the app height and width needs to be set to device height and width to view port to resolve the issue. Below is a sample code to be included in onModuleLoad to resolve the issue.

ViewPort viewPort = new MGWTSettings.ViewPort();
    viewPort.setTargetDensity(DENSITY.MEDIUM);
    viewPort.setUserScaleAble(false) .setMinimumScale(1.0).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMaximumScale(1.0);
    viewPort.setHeightToDeviceHeight();
    viewPort.setWidthToDeviceWidth();